# Problems connecting to my Raspberry via SSH

Tags: networking, raspbian-stretch, port-forwarding, raspbian-lite, bridge

So a little background: I'm a CS student mostly interested in development and software design, but also highly interested in everything Linux and servers. I've wanted my own RPi for a while and finally this week I had the chance to get one and start getting dirty with it. I got myself an Raspberry Pie Model 3+ Starter Kit.

So I decided to start off with something simple: getting a web server running and having Wordpress on top of it. I'm using Raspbian Stretch Lite. Everything works quite well, but I'm having some issues connecting to my RPi. I of course want it to have a public IP so I can connect to it remotely as well and have my website running publicly, so I've tried to achieve it in two ways:

### 1. Bridging the ethernet port on my router which is connected to the RPi

Everything worked quite nicely, outside my local network. So for example if I tried to connect to the website (http) on my cell phone (which was connected to 4G network) it was succesfull, as well as if I tried to connect to the SSH on my cell phone. *BUT* if I tried to connect to the RPi via HTTP or SSH on any of the devices in my LAN (devices that are connected to the same router as RPi, via Wi-fi or ethernet), the connection was unsuccessful.

### 2. Port forwarding the RPi

So since the bridging didn't seem to work, I tried if I can achieve it easily by port forwarding the SSH and HTTP ports from my router to my RPi.

[image: Port forwarding]

The problem I ran into was that now I was able to connect to the RPi via HTTP and SSH *only* through devices that were connected to the router by Ethernet. From devices outside my local network (for example my cellphone that was connected to the 4G) OR devices that were connected to the router via Wi-fi I was only able to access the website through HTTP, but I could not connect to it via SSH.

I'd really appreciate help with this, as I understand that I'm obviously missing or forgetting something really obvious. I'd appreciate help and answers to these questions:

1. Which one is a better solution to get a public ID for my RPi, so it can be connected from outside of my LAN. Bridging an ethernet port or port forwarding?
2. What am I missing, what causes these kinds of problems? I have very basic knowledge on networks through my studies (I'm just starting my 2nd year studies) and through work (I've been working since April solving problems with consumer level network devices), but obviously I'm missing some key pieces in here.

Thanks already!

### Edit:

So the dumbass brains that I have didn't realize that FTP != SSH. Obviously I need to port forward port 22 to be able to connect through SSH from external network. I forwarded port 22 and now I'm able to connect via SSH to my RPi as well.

*But* the problem still exists in my LAN, with devices that are connected via Wi-fi. So I still am not able to connect to the RPi via SSH using the LAN ip that my RPi has (192.168.10.54), but by using the public IP. With devices that are connected via Ethernet I am able to connect to RPi SSH using the ip 192.168.10.54. Does anyone have any idea why that could be?

Comment: You are aware of the fact that this has nothing to do with `Raspberry` in special but are common network questions better asked on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com) and most likely answerd there?

Comment: Not really, if this is the wrong site I'll post the same question in superuser.com instead. I just thought that this most likely is something that people have dealt with before with RPi, as RPi serving as a web server is probably pretty common?

Comment: @LotPings It depends on ... There may be special settings to configure the specific hardware (e.g. ethernet via USB, wifi without bridging capability). I would suggest to stay here with the question.

Comment: @Ingo agreed, till now OP is unspecific on what `RPi` type, what exact Linux OS. Connecting a zero without (W)-Lan **IS** special otherwise the audience on https://unix.stackexchange.com may be broader to networking/routing/router issues.

Comment: I actually found a stupid mistake in my port forwarding settings. I had forwarded FTP ports 20/21, instead of SSH which is 22. So now I am able to connect to my RPi via SSH from outside of my LAN. The issue still exists with devices connected to my LAN via Wi-fi though... Maybe this is the wrong page after all.

Comment: There is something mixed up and unclear with the configuration. I suggest to setup in two steps: first configure the local area network with a web server on a RPi. What model is it? Second step: open your internet router to get from outside to the web server. I will start with an answer that we can improve step by step. If I'm wrong with my assumptions just correct me there. Do you already have a public ip address? What is it? Btw. in your router you have forwarded `ftp` (ports 20+21) and not `ssh` (port 22).

Comment: *"Which one is a better solution to get a public ID for my RPi"* -> If you want a stable IP (i.e., one which is always the same), beware your ISP almost certainly does not provide this for free, so either you pay them for one (this is probably not cheap), or you use a service such as "no-ip".  Beyond that, this question is now very unclear.  If you are simply asking why you cannot connect to the Pi on the LAN, whittle it down to that and *describe what happens when you try*.

Comment: What is the ip-address and netmask (or the slash notation) of your wifi network? Have computers on the ethernet side ever been able to talk to computer on the wifi side and visa-versa?

Comment: @NomadMaker It seems that this indeed is the problem currently. It looks like I can't ping any of devices on the wi-fi side with a device on the ethernet side, or the other way around. I'll have to see why it's this way and how to fix it, probably something to do with my router settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question: to connect to your web server from
outside the internet it is easier to have a static public ip address,
e.g. from your provider. Then you can simply connect to this address
or by its dns name. The other way your router gets a mostly dynamic
public ip address from your provider. The problem is to get this always
changing ip address. You may use a dynamic DNS service from your
provider or from a third party. Then you only use the fixed dns name.
The changing ip address behind it will be managed by the dynDNS service.

To come to your second question: What are you missing isn't answered in
some sentences. We should do it in two steps: first configure the local
area network with a web server on a RPi. Any device on LAN and wifi can
connect to the web site of the web server and via ssh. All devices can
get into the internet via the router. The second step then is to open
your router to get access from the internet to your web site and via ssh
only to the web server. I assume this environment:

```
        (dhcp)
          /    wlan
cell-phone <.~.~.~.~-~.>                  +------------+
                        \                 |  INTERNET  |
        (dhcp)           \     (dyn-ip)   |            |
          /               \      /        |     G4     |
  PC(eth0) <-------------> ROUTER <-----> |      \     |
              ethernet    /\        wan   | cell-phone |
 RPI(eth0) <------------->  \             |            |
          \              192.168.10.1     |            |
     192.168.10.54                        +------------+
```

Clean up your router from any port forwarding. Setup wifi to bridge with
ethernet (that's mostly default). Many router have a security option
that devices connected to wifi cannot talk to other devices on wifi.
If possible enable this feature (on my router it's possible). I also
suppose that a DHCP server on your router is enabled and that you have
the RasPi with the web server given a static ip address 192.168.10.54.
There is also a ssh server running.

Now any device can ping any other device on the network and any device
can browse the web site and can ssh into the web server.

The router has a wan connection to your provider using NAT (network
address translation from source ip to (dyn-ip)) so all devices
can go into the internet. The router gets on wan side an ip address
(dyn-ip) from the provider that changed occasionally. Because of
the nature of NAT there is no traffic possible from the internet into the
local network.

If all is running this way you can now poke two holes into the firewall
(NAT) of your router with port forwarding. That means all traffic
coming in to (dyn-ip) on port 22 (ssh) or port 80 (http) should be
forwarded to ip address 192.168.10.54 port 22 or 80. The daemons behind
these ports on the RasPi (ssh server and web server) will serve the
connection.

Now the cell phone on the internet can also browse your web site and can
ssh into the web server if it knows the (dyn-ip). To solve this look at the answer to your question 1. For testing you can look at the router what ip address it just has got from the provider.

Answer (score 0):

There are three possibilities when trying to connect on a network fails:

1. **Connection times out.** This means either there is no such address, or a firewall is silently discarding packets.  The latter is considered a bad practice, and the only way this could happen on the Pi is if you intentionally configured a firewall that way.

   In your case, this may mean the Pi is not properly on the LAN, which is an issue with either the Pi configuration, the router configuration, or both.

   I have noticed that it is possible to be connected to the internet via a router that is not passing on your local traffic (which would cause a timeout).  In this case, try shutting the connection down, clear the contents of `/var/lib/dhclient` if any (these are DHCP lease records, but I am not sure if Raspbian currently uses `dhclient`), and reconnect.
2. **Connection refused.** This indicates there is no server listening on the requested port.

   In your case, this means either the server you think is running is not running (or not running on the port you think it is), or else this is the wrong IP address and you are being refused by some other device on the LAN.
3. **Unreachable or Prohibited.** This indicates a firewall denied the connection (which is the normal response of a properly configured firewall, in contrast to the discarding of packets mentioned in #1).

   If you are running a firewall on the Pi, disable it until your sort your more basic problems out.

For more details about this, see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/73782/25985